# Need to create a Channel with WCF service without adding service reference in UWP

Tags: c#, wcf, uwp

I need to access the WCF Service in Universal Windows Platform without adding service reference. I tried to create channel like below.

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
var address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:4684/Service1.svc");
var factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(binding, address); //getting exception in this line.
var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
```

Also I made corresponding changes in `web.config` file, too.

But  I am getting this exception:

> An error occured while loading "ServiceContractAttribute" on type "IMyService".

Note that I didn't have this `IMyService` interface in my WCF Service application. The `IMyService` interface is located in a separate assembly and implemented in this WCF service.

Can any one please help me to resolve this issue in UWP and access to my WCF Service?

Comment: Try the solution in this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b5dadb54-3cfb-4d05-8c89-d1efa7193501/methodaccessexception-when-using-channelfactoryt-or-clientbaset?forum=wpdcapp

Comment: Where is your IMyService located? In a WinRT assembly or a portable?

Comment: So, looks like your IMyService does not have the [ServiceContract] attribute. You may try declaring one in your UWP yourself.